SharePoint item level permissions
Our team has a SharePoint, and there are certain files which are being shared with outside members. I have a list of outside members with all the URLs that they currently have access to. I have the excel file with their email address, I want to add this excel file as a list on SharePoint. Then I will share the list with all the outside members whose IDs are listed in the excel file with the URLs that they access to. But I want the members to see only the rows with their email address and let us know if they still want to retain access to the document. This is for access control.
I have found many videos where I see a similar issue but the list is being created by those users and then they are able to see those items as per item level security, which is not my case.
Here, I have a list already available, so it doesn't have a 'created by' column, how can I apply this access control?
